# Path problems with pytest

Tags: python, path, pytest

I have a class that I am writing tests for. The name of the class is Chain.py. Here is the directory structure:

```
`Markov
 |
 |-> Chain.py
 |-> __init.py__
 |->tests
    |-> conftest.py
    |-> test_object_attributes.py
    |-> __init.py__`
```

The tests for Chain.py are in the tests directory.

The input values are in conftest.py. One of the inputs, specified in this file, is a list: states_list.

The first set of tests are in test_object_attributes.py.

Here is the problem:

When I run pytest in the directory Markov, I get an error: 
    `NameError: name 'states_list' is not defined`

When I run pytest in the Markov/tests directory, I get an error:
    `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Chain`

Any ideas on how to solve this problem.
Many Thanks.

Comment: Look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#modules) for how to import functions.